# Rails 4, How to include html5shiv in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

**Context:**

I am using `rubber gem` to deploy my rails app to aws.
It take cares of precomiling on aws.

Everything was working fine, then I added `html5shiv` and `respond.js` for ie8.

I added,

```
/[if lt IE 9]
   = javascript_include_tag 'html5shiv', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
   = javascript_include_tag 'respond', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true
```

It's `slim` but can be easily understood.

`html5shiv.js` and `respond.js` are both in `vendor/assets/javascripts` directory.

Everything works fine on development, but on deployment to aws, I get an error 'permission denied accessing `vendor/assets/fonts` directory'.

I guess, my `html5shiv` and `respond` are not getting compiled and thus rails is requesting them from `vendors` directory.

**Question:**

Do I need to add a reference in `application.js`, even though I have included them with `javascript_include_tag` ?

What would be a rails 4.0 approach to this task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do I need to add a reference in application.js, even though I have included them with javascript_include_tag ?**

No, I didn't need to add a reference in *application.js*.

But, I added,

`config.assets.precompile += ['html5shiv.js', 'respond.js']`

in *config/environments/production.rb*.

**What would be a rails 4.0 approach to this task ?**

Still not sure, if this is the best approach.